# Auto populating a table from another table in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

Actually, let me modify the question with some vba codes. Basically, I have three tables that represent the departments of employees, Information Systems, Finance and Operations. These three tables have certain fields in common while there're some fields that are unique to them. I have a drop down with the following values: IS, FN and OP which represents emp_department. I want to write a vba code on the save button event that will check if the value selected is IS, the record should save in the Information Systems Table, and if FN, the values should save in Finance Tabe, and if OP, the values should save in Operations Table. I wrote the below code but couldn't achieve that. Would really be grateful if this could work.

```
Option Compare Database

Function getPayload(formName As String, tableName As String) As String
Dim formFields As Variant
Dim fieldIndex As Integer
formFields = getTableFields(tableName)

Dim formDictionary As New Dictionary
For fieldIndex = 0 To UBound(formFields)
    Set formDictionary(formFields(fieldIndex)) = _
        Forms(formName).Controls(formFields(fieldIndex))
Next fieldIndex
End Function
Function populateInformationSustemsFields(formName As String, record As Dictionary)
Forms(formName).Controls("emp_depart").SetFocus

If record("emp_depart") = "IS" Then
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO InformationSustmes(formFields)"
End Sub
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Duplicated data is evil. If you explain what you want to achieve with this construction, there is most certainly a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that's exactly what you need but you can simply use SQL statements INSERT+SELECT :

```
INSERT INTO yourTableToPopulate(field1,...,fieldN)
SELECT field1,...,fieldN FROM yourInitialTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion #1:**

Use a bound form for data entry / modification. This will save you a *lot* of code and bug hunting.

- Switch the form `RecordSource` depending on emp_department
- Hide all controls that belong to other departments (this part you need anyway). This is best done by assigning tags to the controls.

**Suggestion #2 (independent of #1):**

Have a combined "Employees" table with the columns that they have in common.

Have additional tables for the extra columns only, in a 1:1 relation. Use queries instead of tables to show all employees of one department, and as recordsource of the form.

or **#2a:** (by far the easiest)

Use a single table with all columns. Only fill the fields that are relevant for the department, the others stay empty.

Comment: **#2a** is indeed the easiest but that's a bad practice. When building your db structure you have to normalize it in order to avoid redundancy & fields interdependances. By merging the 3 tables you will create dependency between your fields. (Some fields will remain blank or not depending on the value of the department field)